# Save the same content to .csv file as print command

Tags: python, csv, save

Print command showing me something like this (I have more as 3 rows, but this is only part of example):

```
O;4;Line[63];CPUA.DB1610.4122,X1;RW
V;5;Enable_maintenance_mode;;
V;5;Maintenance_start_motor;CPUA.DB1610.4124,X0;RW
O;4;Line[64];CPUA.DB1610.4124,X1;RW
```

I'm trying save the same content on csv file, but on csv I have only one row and this format. The question is, how to save to the csv file the save what print showing ?

```
O,;,4,;,L,i,n,e,[,6,4,],;,C,P,U,A,.,D,B,1,6,1,0,.,4,1,2,4,|,|,X,1,;,R,W
```

They are saving me only one row on csv file

This is my code:

```
for i in range((len(result)-1)):
 print(str(result[i][0]) + ';' + str(result[i][1]) + ';' + result[i][2] + ';' + str(adress[i]))
 with open(source_file[:-4] + '_test.csv', "w") as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerow(str(result[i][0]) + ';' + str(result[i][1]) + ';' + result[i][2] + ';' + str(adress[i]))
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me solve this problem ?

result contains:

```
['V', '5', 'Enable_maintenance_mode', "S7:[CPUA]DB1610', 'X4124.0", 'B', 'RW', '0', "0']"]
['V', '5', 'Maintenance_start_motor', "S7:[CPUA]DB1610', 'X4124.1", 'B', 'RW', '0', "0']"]
['O', '4', 'Line[64]', '', '', "']"]
['V', '5', 'Enable_maintenance_mode', "S7:[CPUA]DB1610', 'X4126.0", 'B', 'RW', '0', "0']"]
```

---

@Martin Evans Your example look really good. But I need only part of row from result and save as csv.
Can I make somethink like this ?

```
csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, lineterminator='\n')
 for line in result:
 #csv_output.writerow(line)
 csv_output.writerow(str(result[line][0]) + ';' + str(result[line][1]) + ';' + result[line][2] + ';' + str(adress[line]))
```

But I have error: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

Comment: I'm updated my question what result contains.

Comment: Is `result`  a string or a list of lists?

Comment: What does `adress` contain? It would need to have as many entries as `result`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The csv library is designed to take a list of column entries and convert it automatically into a whole csv row by adding the necessary delimiters for you. Your print statement is simulating this by appending the `;` between each column entry. You can specify the delimiter to use when creating the `csv.writer`, in your example this is `;`:

```
import csv

result = [
    ['V', '5', 'Enable_maintenance_mode', "S7:[CPUA]DB1610', 'X4124.0", 'B', 'RW', '0', "0']"],
    ['V', '5', 'Maintenance_start_motor', "S7:[CPUA]DB1610', 'X4124.1", 'B', 'RW', '0', "0']"],
    ['O', '4', 'Line[64]', '', '', "']"],
    ['V', '5', 'Enable_maintenance_mode', "S7:[CPUA]DB1610', 'X4126.0", 'B', 'RW', '0', "0']"]]

address = [
    "CPUA.DB1610.4122,X1;RW",
    "",
    "CPUA.DB1610.4124,X0;RW",
    "CPUA.DB1610.4124,X1;RW"]

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=';')

    for r, a in zip(result, address):
        csv_output.writerow(r[0:3] + a.split(';'))
```

When using a `csv.writer()` in Python 3.x, you should always open the file with `w` and set `newline=''`. Also it is easier to iterate through your `result` entries directly without using `range()` and indexing. As you appear to have two equal length lists, you can use `zip` to give you an element from each as you iterate.

This would give you an output file as follows:

```
V;5;Enable_maintenance_mode;CPUA.DB1610.4122,X1;RW
V;5;Maintenance_start_motor;
O;4;Line[64];CPUA.DB1610.4124,X0;RW
V;5;Enable_maintenance_mode;CPUA.DB1610.4124,X1;RW
```

Note, you have not provided a sample for `address` so this is based on your example output.

Comment: Rather than manually trying to add the delimiters, it is better to just create the required list.

Comment: Your example implies you are trying to display the first two entries, and then the whole line again?

Comment: This is adress variable:
`db_adress = re.split(r'[,.:]+', result[l][3])`
.
.
`a = (str(db_adress[1][1:5]) + '.' + str(db_adress[1][6:-1]) + '.' + str(variable))`
adress.append(a)`

Comment: Thank you, works very good :) I need make some small corrections.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to click the grey tick next to the answer to accept it as a solution when you're finished.