# Adding (inserting) array to dict

Tags: python, dictionary

My first question: [Save the same content to .csv file as print command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834400/save-the-same-content-to-csv-file-as-print-command/36834885?noredirect=1#comment61250386_36834885)

I need to insert new values to result[1]. For example:
`result.insert([1][0], 'O')` not working.

What I expected to have:

```
result[1][0] =  'O'
result[1][1] = '1'
result[1][2] = 'CPU'
result[1][3] = ';'
result[1][4] = ';'
```

Already I have some string value on result[1] and I don't want to lose it. That's why I need to insert (not replace) new strings.

---

It's working but it's not that what I expected.
I'm writing:

```
result[1].insert(0, 'O')
result[1].insert(1, '1')
result[1].insert(2, 'CPU')
result[1].insert(3, ';')
result[1].insert(4, ';')
```

The result is:

```
result[1] == ['O', '1', 'CPU', ';', ';', 'O', '2', 'DAT_SCADA_AsiGW_F06_GA01', '', '', "']"]
result[2] == ['O', '3', 'INFO', '', '', "']"]
```

I what to have this:

```
result[1] == ['O', '1', 'CPU', ';', ';',]
result[2] == ['O', '2', 'DAT_GW_F0_G01', '', '', "']"]
result[3] ==  ['O', '3', 'INFO', '', '', "']"]
```

Comment: What is `result`? Very unclear to me what you have and what you're trying to do.

Comment: Your question can't be answered if you don't give us an example of `result`.

Comment: I added some link(where you can look how looks `result`) to question.

Comment: Are you trying to add elements to the start of the list in result[1]?

Comment: Not at start (start is [0] position), and I want to add on second position [1]

Comment: The `result` in the linked question is a list of lists of strings; I can't see a `dict` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result[1].insert(1, 'O')
```

Inserts 'O' into the second (aka. [1]) position of the list in result[1].
Remember that result is a list, whose elements are also lists.

Edit:
To insert another entry into your result list use the following:

```
result.insert(1, ['O', '1', 'CPU', ';', ';',])
```

Comment: I updated question